# Scala - Convert Cloud Event to Avro Format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, spark-avro, cloudevents

I'm working on a project where I need to read data from a data source and encapsulate it into an Avro schema following the CloudEvent standard using Cloudevents Java SDK. I'm struggling to find documentation or examples on how to convert a CloudEvent object to Avro.

I read my data from a data source using Spark

```
val newDataDF = inputDF.withColumn("cloudEventValue", createCloudEventUDF(to_json(struct(inputDF.columns.map(col): _*)))

    private def createCloudEventUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf {
  (newData: String) =>
    val event: CloudEvent = CloudEventBuilder.v1()
      .withId("000")
      .withType("example.demo")
      .withSource(URI.create("http://example.com"))
      .withDataContentType("application/json")
      .withTime(OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis()), ZoneOffset.UTC))
      .withData(newData.getBytes())
      .build()

//I return event.toString, but it's not result I was hoping for. Returning just "event" causes error because Spark has not encoder for CloudEvent class. //
```

Now, I need to write 'newDataDF' to a Kafka topic, but the 'cloudEventValue' column should be in Avro format

I've searched through the Cloudevents-Scala documentation, but I couldn't find clear guidance on how to convert a CloudEvent object to Avro. Can someone provide insights or examples on how to achieve this conversion? Any help or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `newDataDF` is a `Dataframe`. Spark lets you [write Dataframes to a kafka topics in avro format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro) using `spark-avro` which is the tag you added. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to return "val event" as avro in the udf. I didn't find any documentation of this in io.core.CloudEvents

Comment: Not sure if the code you share is complete. Looks like the close curly bracket is missing. If the last line of the function you defined inside `udf`, you should add a new line saying `event` or just remove `val event: CloudEvent = `. Scala takes the last line as the return value

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to wrap the event in a withColumn, like

val newDataDf = enrichedData.withColumn("cloudEventValue", to_avro(cloudEventUDF(to_json(struct(enrichedData.columns.map(col): _*)))))

This code is not working because I can't write a CloudEvent object in a spark column. So I want something that converts me CloudEvent object in Avro format, so I can store it in a dataframe column as avro. Sorry if I was not 100% clear, in case I try to express myself better